# When I copy paste data from excel to outlook, I want to retain the mouse over comment on each cell. How do I do that?

Tags: excel, outlook, excel-2016, outlook-2016

When I copy paste data from excel to outlook, I want to retain the mouse over comments on each cell. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

First copy paste your data in Microsoft Word and then manually add comments by selecting each cell

Select the text or item that you want to comment on, or click at the end of the text.

On the Review tab, in the Comments group, choose New Comment.

Add comments

then select all and copy paste the data into outlook

Comment: I have tried this but it's not working as you said. It might have worked prior to outlook 2016.